# Trouble Installing Tensorflow - Building wheel for wrapt (setup.py) ... error

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.6

Whenever I try to install tensorflow I keep getting the following error message. Is there an easy fix for problem?

(py3.6) C:\Users\matthew>pip install tensorflow --no-cache-dir

Collecting tensorflow

Downloading tensorflow-2.1.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (355.9 MB)

...

Building wheels for collected packages: wrapt

Building wheel for wrapt (setup.py) ... error

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Comment: a simple conda install works

Comment: Hi, I had the same problem but conda helped, thanks.